# How do you levitate a foam rock? ('Endless Second' artwork)

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, levitation

I saw this in an art museum:

[image: Floating Rock]

How is this possible? The materials used to make this were foam, wood, stone dust, paint, electromagnets, and metal. I would like to know how this was make and how I could make something similar.

Comment: It's Agnieszka Kurant's "Endless Second". Many artists tried this floating before but they failed. One may get floating metalic objects in "Meissner effect". More modernly, one may create magnets that stabilize the object dynamically by changing the magnetic fields etc. Search for "segway", the scooter that maintains an unnatural balance as well. I don't know what she's really done, it's cool, but it's plausible that there is some invisible support - everything in glass etc. or something.

Comment: @LubošMotl great answer bro  i like it

Comment: There is an image showing more of the empty space surrounding the "Endless Second" sculpture: http://magazynszum.pl/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/SZUM-20131224-11-201.jpg (Image from http://magazynszum.pl/do-zobaczenia/exformation-agnieszki-kurant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumptions of the famous Earnshow's theorem  on the impossibility of levitation have some "loopholes" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem ), one of them is alternating current electromagnets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_levitation#Oscillating_electromagnetic_fields ). Probably, that is the principle used for the installation. Another "loophole" is diamagnetism (not necessarily the Meissner's effect in superconductors mentioned by L. Motl).

Comment: Is it as simple as connecting a coil to a Alternating current?

Comment: @user52453: If you mean to have an alternating current electromagnet, then yes. But finding a stable configuration may be relatively difficult.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Also, thank you very much you have been very helpful.

Comment: @user52453: The following source from the Wikipedia article seems relevant: http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/demobook/chapter5.htm . But please don't do anything like that if you don't know exactly what you're doing. I don't want you to be electrocuted. Safety first - the phrase is boring but you better remember it.

Comment: In that article they use an alternating current but that have two coils, one on the top and one on the bottom the sculpture had nothing above it.

Comment: @user52453: OK, I I did not realize that. I cannot derive a stable configuration. I can only give the following reference: B.V. Jayawant, "Electromagnetic Levitation and Suspension Systems", Publishers: Edward Arnold, London, 1981 (I haven't seen this book myself). I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve, but maybe you might be interested in the stable equilibrium of, say, a ping-pong ball in an upwards air jet.

Comment: @user52453 When you say "the sculpture had nothing above it" - do you mean open sky, or is that "nothing" something like "normal room ceiling" - which may be or contain part of the sculptures mechanism?